# Data Structures in Java & Python and their implementations: Lists, Arrays, Tuples

Tags: java, python, arrays, list, tuples

I know Java and also recently started learning Python. At one point I understood that I need to take a pause and clarify all questions related to Data Structures, especially Lists, Arrays and Tuples. Could you please correct me if I am wrong in any of the following:

- Originally, according to Data Structures standards, Lists do not
  support any kind of indexation. The only way to get access to the
  element is through iterations (next method).
- In Java there is actually a way to get access to elements by index (i.e. get(index) method), but even if you use these index-related methods it is still iterating from the first element (or more specifically its reference)
- There is a way in Python to access to Lists elements as we work with arrays in Java, using list[index] syntax, but in reality, even though this data type is called "lists", we do have an array of references in the background and when we refer to the third element, for example, we are referring directly to the 3 element in array to get reference without iteration from the first one (I am pretty sure that I am wrong over here)
- Tuples are implemented in the same way as Lists in Python. The only difference is that they are immutable. But it is still something closer to lists than arrays, because elements are not located contiguously in memory.
- There are no arrays as in Python
- In Data Structure theory, when we are creating an array, it uses only a reference to the first cell of memory, and then iterates to the # of element that we specified as index. The main difference between Lists and Arrays is that all elements are located contiguously in memory, that's why we are winning in performance aspect.

I am pretty sure that I am wrong somewhere. Could you correct me please?
Thanks

Comment: The primary issue is that you are actually talking about three data structures. A linked-list, an array, and a dynamic array. A Python list is a dynamic array. I recommend reviewing the Wikipedia pages for each of them to get an overview.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am not talking about languages. That was a question about data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of that is wrong.

- The [list abstract data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type%29) is an ordered sequence of elements, allowing duplicates. There are many ways to implement this data type, particularly as a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), but most programming languages use [dynamically resized arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).
- Even linked lists may support indexing. There is no way for the implementation to skip directly to the n'th element, but it can just follow links to get there.
- Java's [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) type does not specify an implementation, only an interface. The [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) type is a List implemented with a dynamic array; the [Linkedlist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is exactly what the name says.
- Python's lists are implemented with dynamically resized arrays. Python's tuples are implemented with fixed-size arrays.
- There are actually two Python types commonly referred to as arrays, not counting the common newbie usage of "array" to refer to Python lists. There are the arrays provided by the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module, and there are [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)'s `ndarray`s.
- When you index an array, the implementation does not iterate from the location of the first element to the n'th. It adds an offset to the address of the array to skip to the element directly, without iterating.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. When I was talking about "implementations" I did not mean java'a interfaces and implementations. So first 3 bullets are pretty clear to me. The same is about Python's arrays-lists controversy. If to wrap up what I understood, is it right that Python's list and tuples are implemented with "arrays" in Data Structure understanding of the word? One is dynamically resized and another one is fixed? And that acces to elements in arrays does not involve iteration? It uses offset + position of the first element?